# Switching original backup from Timemachine

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, backup

Im using the WD My Passport for Mac, and I recently formatted my entire computer. If I use this same harddrive to back up on time machine(with the old backups), will it mess anything up as it might recognize it as a different computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have completely formatted your computer then Time Machine will recognize your computer as a different one, and therefore the backups will be placed in a separate folder on your Time Machine hard drive.